# Does ethereum or blockchain blocks in general use any specific format to store data on local instant?

Tags: blockchain, peers

For example if I store a text file locally it will have .txt extension similarly .jpg in case of images or .mp4 in case of video, so what it would be in case of block record. Can files be located on particular path on local file system.

Answer (score 2):

Ethereum stores its state data in a [LevelDB](https://github.com/google/leveldb) database. The associated file type is `.ldb`.

The state data is [RLP](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Design-Rationale#rlp)-encoded before being inserted into the database, so if you want to read the data you have to both understand the database's schema, and decode the RLP serialisation. You can't just read these files as-is.

```
> ~/.ethereum/geth/lightchaindata/
000042.ldb  000046.ldb  000049.ldb  000052.ldb  000055.ldb  000058.ldb  000061.ldb  000064.ldb  000067.ldb  000070.ldb  000073.ldb  000076.ldb  000079.ldb  000082.ldb  LOG
000043.log  000047.ldb  000050.ldb  000053.ldb  000056.ldb  000059.ldb  000062.ldb  000065.ldb  000068.ldb  000071.ldb  000074.ldb  000077.ldb  000080.ldb  CURRENT     MANIFEST-000000
000045.ldb  000048.ldb  000051.ldb  000054.ldb  000057.ldb  000060.ldb  000063.ldb  000066.ldb  000069.ldb  000072.ldb  000075.ldb  000078.ldb  000081.ldb  LOCK
```